# Как осуществить работу с Instagram API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, instagram, instagram-api

Возникла задача выводить на сайте несколько свежих фото из Инстаграм. Зарегистрировался в https://www.instagram.com/developer/register/ и получил идентификатор
[image: CLIENT ID]

Но при попытке выполнить код...

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { client_id: '[_my_client_id_]' },
        success: function( response ) {

          console.log( response );


        },
        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

          console.log( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown );

        }
      });
    </script>
```

Происходит ошибка:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '[http://[*domain*].ru](http://[_domain_].ru)' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

[image: Ошибка]

Подскажите как решить эту проблему.

Comment: Скорее всего ошибка доступа из-за того, что ваш сайт без шифрования (http) обращается к апи с шифрованием (https). Переведите свой сайт на https или используйте апи без шифрования, если там есть такое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решилась путём написанию кода на back-end с использованием CURL:

```
   try {

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest' ) );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        $result=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $result = json_decode( $result, true );

    } catch ( \Exception $e ) {

        $result = null;

    }
```